# Azure FaceAPI Face is Not Found in Android Java

Tags: java, android, azure, face-api

I am trying to build a face recognition attendance system using Azure FaceAPI. I created a face list. Then, I downloaded the images' URLs from firebase and then used the detection method to detect each face. I added each face to the face list. Finally, I wanted to test findSimilar method by giving it an existing face with the faces UUID array.
These are some parts of the code (I used a thread for each call)

```
private FaceServiceClient faceServiceClient=new FaceServiceRestClient("https://train.cognitiveservices.azure.com/face/v1.0/",key); 
--
faceServiceClient.createFaceList(faceListId, "mylist", "recognition_04");
--
// in a loop from i=0 --> i < no of images
faces= faceServiceClient.detect(Urls.get(i), false, false, null);
facesIds.add( faceServiceClient.addFacesToFaceList(faceListId, Urls.get(i), null, faces[0].faceRectangle).persistedFaceId);
--
faceServiceClient.findSimilar(id,ids, 1 );
```

I printed out all the IDs and checked that they exist. However, it always gives an error after calling findSimilar method.

```
com.microsoft.projectoxford.face.rest.ClientException: Face is not found.
```

Can someone please tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Check your URL endpoint, for example: `https://<resource_name>.cognitiveservices.azure.com/face/v1.0/detect`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detection failed: Resource not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764249/detection-failed-resource-not-found)

Comment: References: [Can you tell me why show message “Resource not found” Microsoft Cognitive Face API in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65894664/can-you-tell-me-why-show-message-resource-not-found-microsoft-cognitive-face-a), [Facing Error "404 Resource Not Found" while consuming Face Detection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/64614/facing-error-34404-resource-not-found34-while-cons.html) and [How to Use Microsoft's Face API for Identifying user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49797903/how-to-use-microsofts-face-api-for-identifying-user)

Comment: not yet. I think the endpoint that I entered is correct because I can see that the deployments are successful in the Azure portal. The only problem is with findSimilar method. Should I use another endpoint for that?

Comment: I just figured out the problem! It was from the Face ID. Just for testing, I used an existing ID of a face from the face list. However, it seems that the ID should be from the detection results instead.

Comment: You can post this as an answer so that it might be helpful to other community members who might face the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simply that findSimilar method takes the ID of detected face not a faceID from the faceList.
For me, I used an existing faceID just to test. However, I had to detect a face then get its ID.

```
faceServiceClient.findSimilar(id,ids, 1 );
```

Summary: Replace 'id' with detected face ID.